# Spaghetti like plot in python from a txt file with blank lines separations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a txt file which is 2 columns and 240k rows like this

```
1   2
2   3
.   .
.   .
4   5


7   9
10  8
12  9
.   .
.   .
e-3 72
```

etc. repeating random numbers in many many 2 column blocks.

I would like a code to make a spaghetti-like plot in which x are the numbers on the left and y the number in the right. The thing is, one plot line should be one block x and y and the black line is a separation that means that the second block x and y is a different plot line. I haven't found any reference about that online. Please help me
My current code that I use is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x,y=np.loadtxt('PHDOS2.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
x=x*27211.3
y=y/27211.3
plt.plot(x,y, label='Phonons DoS')



plt.xlabel('Energy (meV)')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.title('Phonons Density of States')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x,y=np.loadtxt('pho.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
for row in range(len(x)):
    x_values = [1,2]
    y_values = [x[row],y[row]]
    if np.mod(row,2)==0:
        plt.plot(x_values,y_values, color='blue')
    else:
        plt.plot(x_values,y_values, color='black')
plt.xticks([1.0,2.0], ['blk X', 'blk Y'])    
plt.show()
```

Should give you the Spaghetti plot with alternative blue-black colour. 
[image]

However, I am not sure what do you mean by `The thing is, one plot line should be one block x and y and the black line is a separation that means that the second block x and y is a different plot line. I haven't found any reference about that online.`

Comment: What I mean is that, since the .txt file is 2 columns and 240k with multiple blank lines separations, what I need to do is to plot every single blocks in one figure, kinda as you did. I will try it out and let you know, thank you

Comment: Ok, if I get you correctly, you regard rows that are separated by empty row(s) as a "block". Please notice that with `np.loadtxt()` it is impossible to differentiate between blocks (unless you know their indices), because you will have `x=[ 1.  2.  4.  7. 10. 12.]`,  `y=[2. 3. 5. 9. 8. 9.]`, the empty rows were skipped. But if you think my code is helpful in the plotting the Spaghetti, please consider either upvote or accept it as answer.